# Is it possible to pass an object method as argument to a function and bind it to the object?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to make a bind to object method? For example, I have a vector and a lot of functions which do something if some item exists in the vector. I would implement it as follows:

```
fn perform_if_exists(item: u8, vector: &Vec<u8>, func: fn(usize)) {
    let idx = vector.iter().position(|i| *i == item );
    match idx {
        Some(i) => func(i), 
        None    => {},
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    perform_if_exists(1, &v, Vec<_>::remove);
}
```

but it gives a lot of errors. I think they are reasonable but it's because I don't understand how to put vector's method as argument to a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it possible

Sure it is. You have to fix the multiple cascading errors first:

1. Invalid syntax: `Vec<_>::remove` isn't valid.
2. Incompatible argument types: `Vec::remove` modifies **a `Vec`**, so you have to pass in a `Vec` somehow.
3. Mutability: `Vec::remove` **modifies** a `Vec`, so you have to declare that the function is allowed to do so.
4. `Vec::remove` returns the removed value, so you have to allow the function to return a value, even if it's thrown away.

```rust
fn perform_if_exists<F, R>(item: u8, vector: &mut Vec<u8>, func: F)
where
    F: Fn(&mut Vec<u8>, usize) -> R,
{
    let idx = vector.iter().position(|i| *i == item);
    if let Some(i) = idx {
        func(vector, i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    perform_if_exists(1, &mut v, Vec::remove);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

I switched to a generic as that's generally how you will accept closures. A function pointer is fine but more restrictive.

Comment: What if I want to avoid returning value of `Vec::remove`? I mean, I want `perform_if_exists` not only to be able to accept `Vec::remove` as argument because of it's return type. So, for example, I want to have a chance to pass a closure which takes only vector and index of the item, and then performs an action without returning a value and without taking any other arguments

Comment: @VictorPolevoy the code as shown (and also in [Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37392107/155423)) will work with that. *Every* function in Rust returns a value. "Without returning a value" just means that the function returns the empty tuple: `()`. In those cases, `R` would be the empty tuple.

Comment: Excuse me, just understood this.

Answer (score 4):

A method in Rust is nothing more than a function, which also takes a first `self` parameter. The method `Vec::remove` takes two arguments: `&mut self` and `index: usize`. The `self` parameter is always of type `Self`, which is `Vec<u8>` in this case. The complete type of [`Vec::<u8>::remove`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) is: `fn(&mut Vec<u8>, usize) -> u8` (yes it also returns the removed element).

After changing the type in your code (+ a few minor mistakes), it works:

```
//                                      vvv-- has to be mutable
fn perform_if_exists(item: u8, vector: &mut Vec<u8>, func: fn(&mut Vec<u8>, usize) -> u8) {
    let idx = vector.iter().position(|i| *i == item );
    match idx {
        Some(i) => { 
            func(vector, i);
        }, 
        None    => {},
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    perform_if_exists(1, &mut v, Vec::remove);
}
```

But `fn(...) -> ...` types are raw pointer types and just work for ordinary functions. Often you also want to enable the user to pass *anything* that is "callable", like closures. There are traits exactly for that purpose: `Fn(...) -> ...`.

Let me propose another solution:

```
fn perform_if_exists<T, F, R>(item: T, vector: &mut Vec<T>, func: F) -> Option<R>
    where F: FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>, usize) -> R,
          T: PartialEq
{
    let idx = vector.iter().position(|i| *i == item );
    idx.map(|i| func(vector, i))
}
```

This solution is far more generic as it allows arbitrary item types, arbitrary "callable" types and returns the value that is returned by the given function. Note that the `main` function didn't change; the solution is more generic, but all old uses still work.

Comment: What if I want to avoid returning value of `Vec::remove`? I mean, I want `perform_if_exists` not only to be able to accept `Vec::remove` as argument because of it's return type. So, for example, I want to have a chance to pass a closure which takes only vector and index of the item, and then performs an action without returning a value and without taking any other arguments

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but you can pass a function to `perform_if_exists` that returns nothing, too. "returns nothing" is just saying: "returns unit" (where unit = `void` in other languages). `perform_if_exists(1, &mut v, |_, _| {});` works.

Comment: Excuse me, just understood this.