# Giving a method as a parameter in Rust (Vec sort() method)

Tags: rust

I can't figure out how i can give the `sort` method that can be found in the `Vec` implementation here https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort as a parameter.

My code is inspired by the code that can be found in this problem [Is it possible to pass an object method as argument to a function and bind it to the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391695/is-it-possible-to-pass-an-object-method-as-argument-to-a-function-and-bind-it-to), but won't compile.

Here is some example code of what i want to do,

```rust
fn pass_sort<F>(list: &mut Vec<i32>, sort_func: F)
    where F: Fn(&mut Vec<i32>)
{
    sort_func(list);
}

fn main() {
    let mut list: Vec<i32> = vec![3, 2, 1];
    pass_sort(&mut list, Vec::sort);
}
```

and here is the error

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `sort` found for struct `std::vec::Vec<_>` in the current scope
 --> stak_test.rs:9:31
  |
9 |     pass_sort(&mut list, Vec::sort);
  |                               ^^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::vec::Vec<_>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

I guess it happens because `sort` isn't a method of `Vec` but a method from the `Deref<Target=[T]>` implementation as explained in the doc, but i can't figure out how to access the method from this scope :/.

Comment: Other than what's in the answer, another option is to use a closure: `pass_sort(&mut list, |v| v.sort())`. As Rust's closures are zero-cost (inlined wherever possible), I would expect it to result in the exact same code being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it happens because sort isn't a method of Vec but a method from the Deref<Target=[T]>

That is correct, the method comes from [`slice::sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort), so you need to use it instead:

```rust
fn pass_sort<F>(list: &mut Vec<i32>, sort_func: F)
where
    F: Fn(&mut [i32]),
{
    sort_func(list);
}

fn main() {
    let mut list: Vec<i32> = vec![3, 2, 1];
    pass_sort(&mut list, <[i32]>::sort);
}
```

Comment: Owwww thaaanks :), i tried this line `pass_sort(&mut list, <[i32]>::sort);` but i was missing  the parameter type to be `&mut [i32]` in the function signature.